# Retrieve an item in all dictionaries inside another dictionary without using loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionaries inside another dictionary like:

```
dataDict = {"id42": {"fruit": "banana", "person": "Jason"}, "id43": {"fruit": "apple", "person": "Thomas"} }
```

Now I'll like to retrieve 'Jason' and 'Thomas' without using a loop, I'm looking for something like:

```
dataDict[:][person]
```

Where `":"` would be 'all keys'.

I would prefer not using a loop

Comment: You can't do this without a loop, no.

Comment: a bad hardcode - `map(lambda x: dataDict.get(x).get('person'),  dataDict.keys())`

Comment: @marmeladze: why the loop over keys? Just loop over the values; `map(lambda sub: sub['person'], dataDict.values())`, or, using `operator.itemgetter`: `map(itemgetter('person'), dataDict.values())`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  sure -))

Comment: TY for the comments and responses :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without a loop. There is no `:` syntax for Python dictionaries (and even in lists, you need to loop, in the list implementation, to satisfy slices).

Just loop, either using `map()` to do the looping (if you only need an iterable), or use a list comprehension (if you must have a list):

```
from operator import itemgetter

results_iterable = map(itemgetter('person'), dataDict.values())

results_list = [sub['person'] for sub in dataDict.values()]
```